# Output separate js files, but share some code with leiningen?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, clojurescript

I'm a bit confused on how best to set up project.clj for my use case.

We're trying to embed new technology into the old, so we're creating separate pages using cljs and embedding them into our old application (thus, not a "single page app"). So, ideally, one page's javascript would be separated from another. Page X's javascript wouldn't contain Page Y's javascript except whatever functions are common between them.

I'm not really sure how best to set this up in project.clj. Imagine we have some common utilities in the "util" namespace, some code for Page X in the "page-x" namespace, and code for Page Y in the "page-y" namespace. What is the best way of setting this up without duplicating code? Is it possible?

I imagine the directory structure might look something like this:

```
src/cljs/util/...
src/cljs/page-x/...
src/cljs/page-y/...
```

Perhaps if I set up `:source-paths` as `["src/cljs/util", "src/cljs/page-x"]` for the Page X build, and use page-y for the Page Y build? Just include the common code in the array as needed? Perhaps something like:

```
:page-x {
  :source-paths ["src/cljs/util", "src/cljs/page-x"]
  :compiler {
     :output-to "dist/js/page-x.min.js"
     :optimizations :advanced}}

:page-y {
  :source-paths ["src/cljs/util", "src/cljs/page-y"]
  :compiler {
     :output-to "dist/js/page-y.min.js"
     :optimizations :advanced}}
```

I'll keep messing around, but I thought I'd toss out the question as I do so.

Edit: Namespacing issues with the above idea. I have a `src/cljs/util/util.cljs` and `src/cljs/page-x/main.cljs`, for example. I believe the convention is the namespace of the file is the directory it's in, but if `src/cljs/util` is the directory specified in `:source-paths`, it's the root, so there is no namespace for util.cljs that I can tell. This leads me to some lovely `ERROR - required "util.util" namespace never provided` messages when leiningen runs.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell the compiler right now only works for outputing a single file, so no code splitting / common shared code bundles right now.

Tracking jira issue: http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJS-848